# BO webi variable giving second max instread of max

Tags: business-objects

I have been trying to fetch the max of a date variable and when I try to do so, webi gives me second max date instead of the max.

```
   [Var_tran_date]= If([Part Tran Type]="D") Then     
                      (FormatDate(ToDate("10/10/10";"MM/dd/yy");"MM/dd/yy"))ForEach ([SBA,CAA,TDA].[Foracid])
                    Else
                      [Tran Date]
```

foracid here being the account number, The max varible is defined as:

```
   var_maxdate=Max([Var_tran_date]) In ([SBA,CAA,TDA].[Foracid])
```

and the result is giving me second max date for each account number instead of max.

[image: Max date snapshot (last column)]

I am unable to fetch the max date.

Answer (score 0):

The `FormatDate()` call in your variable is causing the result to be a text string value rather than date.  So, your subsequent `Max()` is producing the maximum of the string value of the dates.  In this case, "11/28/14" comes after "1/1/15".

Also the ForEach in var_tran_date is unnecessary and may be getting in the way.

Try either:

```
=If([Part Tran Type]="D") Then     
      ToDate("10/10/10";"MM/dd/yy")
  Else
     [Tran Date]
```

or

```
=If([Part Tran Type]="D") Then     
      (FormatDate(ToDate("10/10/10";"yyyy/MM/dd");"yyyy/MM/dd"))
  Else
      [Tran Date]
```

The first will retain the values as dates, so the Max() will function as expected.  The second formats the dates as a string, but as yyyy/mm/dd so Max() will still produce the expected value